# Getting "401 Unauthorized" when calling an Azure Function the second time

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, http-status-code-401

I have an Azure Function like this:

```
[FunctionName("Exit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger log)
```

This is how I call it from another process:

```
var endpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ExitUrl");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestDto);
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
var key = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Exit-Key");
_httpClientFactory.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-functions-key", key);

var response = await _httpClientFactory.SendAsync(request);
```

The first time I call it everthing is OK.

But the second time and the next ones (within seconds) return a "401 Unauthorized" error

How can I manage this?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you call the function using Postman or similar program?

Comment: Looks like every requests adds the `x-functions-key` to your default headers, even though you only should do that only once for your factory. Might cause the issue, but I'm not certain as I don't know what the implementation is of `DefaultRequestHeaders.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

```
_httpClientFactory.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-functions-key", key);
```

This line was adding several headers repeated (one for each iteration), causing the 401 error